# Is there any palindromic power of $2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion, open-problem

My question is in the title:

> Is it possible to find $n≥4$ such that $2^n$ is a [palindromic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number) (in base $10$)?

A palindromic number is a number which is the same, independently from which side we read it (forwards and backwards), for example $121, 484, 55755$.

---

My guess is "no". I know that a palindromic number $x$ with even length (i.e. the number of digits $\max\{n : 10^n \mid x\}$ is even) is a multiple of $11$: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697096) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57551) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985345). In particular, a power of $2$ with an even length can't be a palindromic number.

However, I don't know what to do with the case of an odd length. For instance, if $x=abcdcba$, then $abccba$ is a multiple of $11$, but I don't see how this can help.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754211/) is a related question. On MathOverflow, related questions are: [(1)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92397/binary-representation-of-powers-of-3) and [(2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111505/does-there-exist-a-n-in-mathbbz-where-n-geq-2-such-that-a-an-an). Maybe also [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707139/) (since $(1)$ is focused on binary expansion).

I tried with Mathematica and there is no palindromic power of $2$ with exponent $n<10000$:

```
 palindromeQ[n_] := IntegerDigits[n] === Reverse@IntegerDigits[n];
 For[i = 1, i < 10000, i++, If[PalindromeQ[2^i], Print[i]] ]
```

Finally, I think that the answer will be the same if we replace $2$ by any integer $n>1$ which is not a multiple of $11$. I don't know how I could prove (even for the case of even length…) that $11^n$ is not a palindromic number for $n≥5$.

Any hint will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: The general claim is false...$2201^3=10662526601$.  No idea about powers of $2$.

Comment: Maybe you could use $11^{n} = (10+1)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} 10^{k}$ for your last problem.

Comment: @lulu, the question was about exponent at least 4. This also rules out $26^2=676$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page on palindromic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number):

> G. J. Simmons conjectured [that] there are no palindromes of form $n^k$ for $k > 4$ (and $n > 1$).

The cited reference is:

> Murray S. Klamkin (1990), Problems in applied mathematics: selections from SIAM review, [p. 577](https://books.google.ch/books?id=tlrkeWlpUlUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Problems+in+Applied+Mathematics&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_xsed5_TKAhXDPxQKHce5B4sQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't looked closely enough at this Wikipedia page. However, the page 520 in that book is only a bibliography for geometry problems. On page 577, the problem 70-8 (the only one I found on palindromic numbers in that book) asks : "Does there exist any number greater than $1$ and not of the form $10 \cdots 01$ whose fourth power is a palindrome?". I have the 1990 edition… I don't know why I don't find precisely this conjecture in this reference.

Comment: On [that page](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1jg11i/does_2k_where_k3_become_a_base_10_palindrome/), another reference is given : G. J. Simmons, Palindromic powers, Journal of Recreational Mathematics, 3 (No. 2, 1970), 93-98.

Comment: I found it! [I love the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002778/a002778_2.pdf)! This is question 5 on page 98.

Comment: (Sorry to post so many comments…). Just out of curiosity, we can read on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Palindromic_number&oldid=414975285) old Wikipedia page: "M. Markovič's conjecture: If $n^4>0$ is a palindrome, then $n$ begins and ends with digit $1$, all other digits of $n$ being $0$. OEIS A186080. This conjecture has been tested by Simmons up to $10^{14}$". See also OEIS A056810.

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=tlrkeWlpUlUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Problems+in+Applied+Mathematics&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_xsed5_TKAhXDPxQKHce5B4sQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a version of Klamkin's book, available online. I let you guess what happens for page 577…

Comment: Just an aside:  Perhaps somebody should edit the Wikipedia page to reflect that correction?

Comment: Does a conjecture answer the question ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust : you could post the same comment on these answers : [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/96639), [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/25669), [(3)](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1576755)…