# Is $\sigma(2^r)$ a palindrome (in base $10$) for some $r > 2$, where $\sigma$ is the sum-of-divisors function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion, divisor-sum, palindrome

(Note:  This post is *a bit* related to this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653079).)

The title says it all.

> Is $\sigma(2^r)$ a palindrome (in base $10$) for some $r > 2$, where $\sigma$ is the sum-of-divisors function?

If $r = 1$, then $\sigma(2^r) = \sigma(2) = 3$ is *trivially* a palindrome.

Similarly, if $r = 2$, then $\sigma(2^r) = \sigma(4) = 7$ is also *trivially* a palindrome.

I noticed that
$$\sigma(2^r) \equiv
\begin{cases}
{
1 \pmod{10}, \hspace{0.1in} r \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \\
3 \pmod{10}, \hspace{0.1in} r \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
7 \pmod{10}, \hspace{0.1in} r \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \\
5 \pmod{10}, \hspace{0.1in} r \equiv 3 \pmod 4
}
\end{cases}
$$

and that the *leading decimal digit* of $\sigma(2^r)$ does not coincide with the *trailing decimal digit*, for *almost all* $r > 2$.  (I arrived at this observation by coding the appropriate cell formulas in a spreadsheet.)

Comment: Note $\sigma(2^r) = 2^{r+1}-1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, is it possible to compute the *leading decimal digit* of $2^{r+1} - 1$ using some formula?

Comment: Sort of. For $k \geqslant 4$, the leading decimal digit of $2^k - 1$ is the leading decimal digit of $2^k$. Then you have $\log_{10} 2^k = k\cdot \log_{10} 2$, and from the fractional part of that you can read off the leading digit(s). For large $k$, however, computing the logarithm with sufficient accuracy becomes complicated.

Comment: Heuristically, Benford's law applies so that we can say that the leading digit is $1$ quite often ...