# How often is $N/(2N-\sigma(N))$ a palindrome (in base-$10$) if $N$ is deficient-perfect?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, palindrome

Let $\sigma(N)$ denote the sum of divisors of the positive integer $N$.

If $(2N-\sigma(N)) \mid N$, then $N$ is said to be [deficient-perfect](http://oeis.org/A271816).

Note that, if $N$ is deficient-perfect, then $N/(2N-\sigma(N))$ is an integer.

Here is my question:

> How often is $N/(2N-\sigma(N))$ a [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number) (in base-$10$) if $N$ is deficient-perfect?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since powers of $2$ are [almost perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number), (in particular, $2(2^r) - \sigma(2^r) = 1$ for integers $r \geq 0$), then they are also deficient-perfect, so that we are led to the related question:

> [Is there any palindromic power of $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1653079)

(The accepted answer to the hyperlinked question above references a conjecture due to Simmons, which predicts that the answer is *NO* for $r \geq 4$.)

We then survey the even deficient-perfect numbers with exactly two distinct prime factors (listed as a subsequence of OEIS sequence [A271816](http://oeis.org/A271816)), for $N \leq 709784$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
\text{$N$} & \text{$N/(2N-\sigma(N))$} & \text{Base-$10$ Palindrome?} & \text{Prime?} \\ \hline
10 & 5 & YES & YES \\ \hline
44 & 11 & YES & YES \\ \hline
136 & 68 & NO & NO \\ \hline
152 & 38 & NO & NO \\ \hline
184 & 23 & NO & YES \\ \hline
752 & 47 & NO & YES \\ \hline
884 & 221 & NO & NO \\ \hline
2144 & 536 & NO & NO \\ \hline
2272 & 284 & NO & NO \\ \hline
2528 & 158 & NO & NO \\ \hline
8384 & 2096 & NO & NO \\ \hline
12224 & 191 & YES & YES \\ \hline
17176 & 113 & NO & YES \\ \hline
18632 & 4658 & NO & NO \\ \hline
18904 & 2363 & NO & NO \\ \hline
32896 & 16448 & NO & NO \\ \hline
33664 & 4208 & NO & NO \\ \hline
34688 & 2168 & NO & NO  \\ \hline
49024 & 383 & YES & YES \\ \hline
63248 & 3953 & NO & NO \\ \hline
85936 & 10742 & NO & NO \\ \hline
106928 & 326 & NO & NO \\ \hline
116624 & 29156 & NO & NO \\ \hline
117808 & 7363 & NO & NO \\ \hline
526688 & 32918 & NO & NO \\ \hline
527872 & 65984 & NO & NO \\ \hline
531968 & 33248 & NO & NO \\ \hline
556544 & 8696 & NO & NO \\ \hline
589312 & 4604 & NO & NO \\ \hline
599072 & 1544 & NO & NO \\ \hline
654848 & 2558 & NO & NO \\ \hline
709784 & 578 & NO & NO \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I am therefore led to conjecture the following prediction:

> **CONJECTURE** If $N > 8$ is an even deficient-perfect number and
> $Q = N/(2N-\sigma(N))$ is a base-$10$ palindrome, then $Q$ is prime.

Notice from the table above that the converse of the **CONJECTURE** is false.

Note that there is a counterexample to the **CONJECTURE** if we restrict $N$ to be odd, since if we consider the lone odd deficient-perfect number that we know of (as of June 2019), then we have
$$N = {3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2} = 9018009$$
$$\sigma(N) = 18035199 = {3^2}\cdot{7}\cdot{13}\cdot{{19}^2}\cdot{61}$$
$$2N - \sigma(N) = 2\bigg({3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}\bigg) - {3^2}\cdot{7}\cdot{13}\cdot{{19}^2}\cdot{61}$$
$$= {3^2}\cdot{7}\cdot{13}\cdot\bigg(2\cdot{7}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{13} - {{19}^2}\cdot{61}\bigg) = {3^2}\cdot{7}\cdot{13} = 819$$
$$\frac{N}{2N-\sigma(N)} = \frac{9018009}{819} = \frac{{3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}}{{3^2}\cdot{7}\cdot{13}} = {7}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{13} = 11011,$$
which is a palindrome, but is composite.

Finally, it is currently unknown whether there are infinitely many palindromic primes (i.e. numbers that are both palindromes and primes), although it is [known](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405056) that "*almost all palindromes are composite*".

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a *partial answer*.

---

I checked for counterexamples to the **Conjecture** using the Pari-GP interpreter of [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1j7EOwjAQQ3_FLJWDgihsDOEPWNmrNqluCEFJVOXzadoiBtTbfO9s-VyILOamcWnX0RBHXo8FdyQZfceiFJoG5CMMLHphpx9TMAbt98bF4AcZJSc-bR_txE0VnPFn3dw7sCYeKOkdxVvuJWjM_JXnZq7rc32nbj9PaTpx&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), in the range $9 \leq N \leq {10}^7$, it only returned the following (odd) counterexample (as expected):

```
9018009[3, 2; 7, 2; 11, 2; 13, 2]
```

(I omitted the code to check only for even counterexamples, to make sure the code was working as designed.)

The Pari-GP interpreter of Sage Cell Server crashes as soon as a search limit of ${10}^8$ is specified.

This gives further computational evidence for the **Conjecture**.